# css 100% height

Tags: css

I have a structure like this

```
<body>
    <div class="level1">
        <div class="level2"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I want to apply 3 different images on body, .level1, level2 all required 100% height. How to apply? min-height: 100% works only for body and level1 but not on level2.

How to apply it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
html, body, div.level1, div.level2
{
    height: 100%;
}
```

And don't forget the doctype!

Comment: Note: This will set the height of those element to exactly 100% of the viewport. If the content expands, it'll cause an overflow.

Comment: @fabsn: True, maybe `min-height` would have been better, but that often has issues. :P Anyway, setting the width/height to 100% of viewport height plus allowing contents to stretch it is always a problem. :P

Comment: True. The problem with min-height is, that it won't work if the parent has no absolute value. So you could set html and body to height:100%, div.level1 to min-height:100% but div.level2 min-height:100% won't work.